# SyntaxError: expected expression, got '&' (Django)

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I have an analytic dashboard with Django as a backend.
After analyzing data in Python I'm sending a dictionary with name and salience.

```
var things_mentioned = {{entity.name}};
var things_salience = {{entity.salience}};
```

which produces an error:
`SyntaxError: expected expression, got '&'`

Below code does not produce any error and works perfectly:

```
var things_mentioned = ['noodles', 'food', 'Chinese', 'flavor', 'umami flavor'];
var things_salience = {{entity.salience}};
```

when I try to view `{{entity.name}}` value in plain HTML page it exactly displays this

> ['noodles', 'food', 'Chinese', 'flavor', 'umami flavor'].

Also, there is not a single '&' in my entire program.

Comment: Can you please supply more information and a stacktrace of the JS error from your console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will try to HTML-escape the string. You can use JavaScript escaping. The safest way is probably to use the [**`|json_script`** template filter [Django-do]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#json-script). You can thus use this as:

```
{{ entity.name|json_script:"things_mentioned" }}
var things_mentioned = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('things_mentioned').textContent);
```